# How to submit on keypress (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I have written a login. Now I want to do this (press return to login):

```
Private Sub login_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, 
               ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Return Then
        login()
    End If
End Sub
```

It does not work. At this time it works only with a button.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the KeyDown events of the textboxes instead.

```
Protected WithEvents txtUsername As TextBox
Protected WithEvents txtPassword As TextBox

Private Sub Login_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtUsername.KeyDown, txtPassword.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Return Then login()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just set the AcceptButton property of your form to be the button you would like to be "pressed" when return/enter is pressed.  This is exactly what this feature is here for.